# Sub-string match in word tokenizer

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have defined a function that returns me the sentences containing specified word from an excel file having a 'text' column. 
And with the help of @Julien Marrec I redefined the function so that I could pass multiple words as argument as below

```
words = ['word1','word2','word3'.......]
df['text'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                                   if any(True for w in word_tokenize(sent) 
                                           if w.lower() in searched_words)])
```

But the problem is dataset is pretty huge(typically in GB's) and unstructured. Can someone suggest me how can I have a substring match to happen too i.e if a sentence has 'xxxxxword1yyyyy' my function should be able to return this sentence as well.

Comment: I understand your question about the sub-word matching (which is also in the title), but I'm not sure what the issue is with the data size. Does processing take too long, or are you running out of memory?

Comment: @lenz I mentioned about the data size only because if someone might suggest stemming because that may take a lot of time! Although stemming would only give me desired output only in some typical cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about word boundaries, you can skip word tokenisation and just match with a regular expression.

However, this might give you a lot of matches that you didn't expect. For example, the search terms "tin" and "nation" will both match in the word "procrastination". If that is what you want, you can do the following:

```
import re

fsa = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(w.lower()) for w in searched_words))
df['text'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                               if fsa.search(sent)])
```

The `re.compile()` expression creates a regex pattern object, which consists simply of a set of alternatives.
This allows you to scan through the complete sentence, looking out for all of the searched words at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a ton that worked. But if my text has "Python is dangerous.I am afraid" and searched_words has 'python' in it. The output I am getting is ['Python is dangerous.I am afraid'] instead of ['Python is dangerous.'] If I have a space in between sentences then and there only I am getting the right output. Suggest me if you can.

Comment: And the idea of removing boundaries is what I never thought as such. thank you.

Comment: For improving the sentence splitting, you can retrain the Punkt sentence tokeniser. That works well for finding abbreviations, ie. dots that aren't sentence boundaries, but I'm not sure if it helps with missing whitespace after full stops. Maybe ask this in a seperate question.